# best curve fitting the distribution

Tags: numpy, plot, scipy, model-fitting

I tried to use a polynomial (3-degrees) to fit a data series, but it seems that it's still not the best fit (some points are off in graph shown below). I also tried to add a log function to help plot. But result is not improved either.

What would be the best curve fitting here?

Here are the raw data points I have:

`x_values = [ 0.51,0.56444444,0.61888889 , 0.67333333 , 0.72777778, 0.78222222, 0.83666667, 0.89111111 , 0.94555556 , 1.  ]
y_values = [0.67154591, 0.66657266, 0.65878351, 0.6488696, 0.63499979, 0.6202393, 0.59887225, 0.56689689, 0.51768976, 0.33029004]`

Results with polynomial fit:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be better, if your curve fitting procedure were hypothesis driven, i.e., you had already an idea, what kind of relationship to expect. The shape looked to me more like an exponential function:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#the function that describes the data    
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(b * x + c) + d

x_values = [0.51,0.56444444, 0.61888889, 0.67333333 , 0.72777778, 0.78222222, 0.83666667, 0.89111111 , 0.94555556 , 1.  ]
y_values = [0.67154591, 0.66657266, 0.65878351, 0.6488696, 0.63499979, 0.6202393, 0.59887225, 0.56689689, 0.51768976, 0.33029004]

#start values [a, b, c, d]
start = [-.1, 1, 0, .1]
#curve fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x_values, y_values, p0 = start)
#output [a, b, c, d]
print(popt)

#calculating the fit curve at a better resolution
x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_values), max(x_values), 1000)
y_fit = func(x_fit, *popt)
    
#plot data and fit
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, label = "data")
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, label = "fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

This still does not look correct, the first part seems to have a linear offset. If we take this into consideration:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c, d, e):
    return a * np.exp(b * x + c) + d * x + e

x_values = [0.51,0.56444444, 0.61888889, 0.67333333 , 0.72777778, 0.78222222, 0.83666667, 0.89111111 , 0.94555556 , 1.  ]
y_values = [0.67154591, 0.66657266, 0.65878351, 0.6488696, 0.63499979, 0.6202393, 0.59887225, 0.56689689, 0.51768976, 0.33029004]

start = [-.1, 1, 0, .1, 1]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x_values, y_values, p0 = start)
print(popt)

x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_values), max(x_values), 1000)
y_fit = func(x_fit, *popt)

plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, label = "data")
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, label = "fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

we have the following output:
[image]

This now is closer to your data points.
BUT. You should go to your data and think about, which model is most likely to reflect reality, then implement this model. You can always construct more complicated functions that better fit your data, but they do not necessarily reflect better reality.